# What is wrong with my acer palmatum? What should I do?

Tags: leaves, maple, dryness, hot-weather

I have recently purchased an *acer palmatum* and everything looked ok at first. However, in the last few days, some of the leaves on the top and bottom have started to dry and some have fallen. I have been watering it regularly as the land has seemed a little dry.
In the morning, the acer is totally in the shade, it only starts to get direct sunlight from 1pm. Where I live it has been very hot (temperatures between 25ºC and 30ºC or more).
I'm worried, what should I do?

(I'm sorry in advance if my English is not the best)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it a bit windy where you've stood it? Is it still in the same pot it was in when you bought it? What part of the world are you in?

Comment: I live in a coastal area, close to the beach and the sea. It is not very windy in here in this time of the year. And yes, it is in the same pot it was when I bought it in May or June (I'm not sure when exactly)

Comment: I meant what part of the world (what state in the USA, or other country) rather than your local conditions, though knowing  its coastal and close enough to the sea to be subject to possible salt breezes is useful. It only matters in terms of being able to work out the climate where you are...

Comment: I don't want to be very specific, I'm sorry! But is temperate/ Mediterranean climate

Comment: That helps a bit...

Comment: I'm glad to know. Is there any way you can help?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to do is move your tree into a larger pot with drainage holes (the one you have it standing inside seems to be about the right size), using new potting soil to pack round the root ball. Water thoroughly with a few litres of water afterwards, and allow the excess to drain away freely from the bottom of the pot. Ongoing. water when the surface of the soil feels just slightly dry to the touch; water thoroughly with 2-3 litres of water.

There does appear to be a small amount of wind damage, but otherwise, it may have baked a bit in the sun and the roots may have become a bit dry. It will be easier to keep the plant well watered once it's in a larger pot, where it will have access to damp soil, rather than being a solid root ball in a smaller pot with not much free soil around it.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll try it and let you know if it worked.